# calling exports.start in same js file node.js

Tags: node.js

Hi this is my method in a node js file:

```
exports.start = function() {
    console.log(' in start of sender.js');
});
```

How can I call this method in the same js file? I tried calling start() and exports.start() but not successful.

Answer (score 90):

Use this code:

```
var start = exports.start = function() {
   console.log(' in start of sender.js');
});
```

or

```
function start() {
   console.log(' in start of sender.js');
});

exports.start = start;

//you can call start();
```

Comment: or `exports.start =  function start() {
   console.log(' in start of sender.js');
});`

Answer (score 46):

```
exports.start = function(){
    console.log('testing...')
}
```

You can call this method like this

```
    exports.start();
```

Answer (score 14):

You can call the exported function like this

> module.exports.functionName(arguments);

Answer (score 1):

Your named function:

```
var start = function() {
   console.log(' in start of sender.js');
});
```

And later export object:

```
module.exports = {start : start}
```

So you can call `start()` in the same js file

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing on my computer is the following, and working well  - please comment if you think it's a bad idea !

Let's say you're on `file.js`

```
const onThisFile = require("./file");

exports.get = async (args) => .... // whatever;
exports.put = async (args) => .... // whatever;
exports.post = async (args) => .... // whatever;
exports.delete = async (args) => .... // whatever;

exports.doSomething = async (args) => onThisFile.get(args)
```